# Django with NoSQL

Tags: sql, django, nosql

I want to create a website using django to visualize data for companies, and I have the data in json file represented as:

```
[{'label': 'BMW',
  'gain': [{'cash': 198,
    'visa': 923,
    'year': 1988},
   {'cash': 112,
    'visa': 313,
    'year': 1989}],
  'type': 'automobile'}]
```

Is it better to create two tables for each year or I should use NoSQL database with django?
I don't have any experience with NoSQL, can you tell which is easier to use?

Answer (score 0):

Django by default contains an Object-Relational Mapping layer which makes it easy to handle this type of data. You might want to choose which to use depending on your needs for example how you would want to access the data in the frontend. Django definitely provides more support for the SQL databases than the NoSQL databases.

I would write the model for the data you posted as:

```
from django.db import models

TYPES = [('automobile', 'Automobile'), ('finance', 'Finance'), ...]

class Gain(models.Model):
    cash = models.FloatField()
    visa = models.FloatField()
    year = models.FloatField()

class Company(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    gain = models.ManyToManyField(Gain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TYPES)

    @property
    def display_gain(self):
        gains = [gain for gain in self.gain.values('cash', 'visa', 'year')]
        return gains
```

To get the data you typed out in views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def view(request):
    company = Company.objects.get(pk=1)
    payload = {
        'label': company.label, 
        'gain':company.display_gain, 
        'type': company.get_type_display()
    }
    data = json.dumps(payload)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```